# Get a related item using selectors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux to fetch posts, every post has a user. My normalised data is as follows

```
{
    entities: {
        posts: {
            4: {
                name: 'Post 4',
                user: 5
            }
        }
        users: {
            5: {name: 'User 5'}
        }
    },
    post: {
        id: 4
    }
}
```

I'm using a selector to get the current post

```
post: getPost(state.entities.posts, 4)


export const getPost = (posts, id) => posts[id];
```

**How can I get the user's name for this particular post?**

I'm wondering what would be a good way of getting the user information as well, for that post, using selectors.

Comment: not sure what you are asking. you need to take the output of `getPath` and use it to retrieve in this case the user with id 5?

Comment: Sorry typo! Supposed to be Post. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: Is there a getPost function or you want this from us? I didn't understand you exactly.

Comment: I added the getPost selector function, I'm wondering how to fetch the user's name for that particular post

Comment: edited. Typo :)

Comment: can `user` has multiple id? like `user: [5,6,7]` and do you want to get all from `users`

Comment: There will only be 1 user, normalise throws it in an array for some reason. I'll edit the code so it says user: 5 instead of user: [5]

Comment: Why you don't use `getPost(state.entities.users, getPost(state.entities.posts, 4).user[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create two specific selectors to retrieve posts and users

```
const getPost = (posts, postId) => posts[postId]
const getUser = (users, userId) => users[userId]
```

And then a "complex" selector that combines the two

```
const getPostUser = (state, postId) => {
    const userId = getPost(state.posts, postId).user
    return getUser(state.users, userId)
}
```

Comment: This is difficult since I'm always passing the state slice to the selector, so for example getPost(state.posts), getUser(state.users), since I read that a selector takes the state, and returns items from it. Given that the state has to be passed each time it's impossible to use the above way I suppose?

Comment: you could pass `state.entities` to `getPostUser`. edited answer to match your desired api

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
export const getPost = (posts, id) => {
  const post = posts[id];
  post.user = state.entities.users[post.user].name;
  return post;
}
```

Comment: Aha, that's a good plan, preloading the data in my post selector, I didn't even think of that! Thank you.